# Please suggest a .NET 2.0 based OpenXML library

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, docx, xlsx

I know that Microsoft's OpenXML SDK is for .NET 3.5. I am looking for a .NET 2.0 library that could manage xlsx, docx formats. And can change the office format properties.

Comment: .NET 3.5 uses the same runtime, so should still run - though I've never tried to add a .NET 3.5 dll to a .NET 2 project so I've no idea if you can link it at compile time.

Comment: v1 of the library only requires v3.0 of the Framework; It might also be helpful to explain why you cannot move to a later version of the framework.

Comment: We are developing the end-user software that could be downloaded from the Internet by anyone. .NET 2.0 is installed on the most PCs while 3.0 is not widely adopted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no library for 2.0. What you'll need to do is manually work with Open XML. First you'll need an unpacking/repacking function (not sure if WindowsBase which hosts `System.IO.Packaging` is available for 2.0, but you can use other zip utilities).

Comment: Otaku, thanks for your reply. I've seen your replies on many topics here related to OpenXML. Unfortunatelly WindowsBase is available for .NET 3.0 only.

Comment: @Murat: Yeah, in that case you'll need to use another zip library (like SharpZipLib). And old-school XML processing (XSLT processing is an option as well). I'm sure it can be done though, it just takes a bit more work. If you look at the ODF->OOXML converter on SourceForge, you'll see that it uses .NET 2.0 (and mostly XSLT).

Comment: Otaku, thanks for your input. I'll try to manually process XML.

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose](http://www.aspose.com) supports all the different .Net framework versions, and can manipulate both DOCX and XLSX. It isn't free however, so it may or may not help.